# Where does the xmm instruction "divsd" store the remainder

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

In the statement:

```
divsd xmm0,xmm1
```

where is the remainder stored?  Do the xmm registers have a register for the remainder, like the integer registers?  Should I use FPREM in the x87 instructions instead?

As far as I've found, the Intel manuals are silent on this issue, and a lot of research has not produced a useful answer.

Comment: `divsd` does not calculate a remainder.

Comment: [`divsd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIVSD.html): *Divides the low double-precision floating-point value in the first source operand by the low double-precision floating-point value in the second source operand, and **stores the double-precision floating-point result in the destination operand*** so how do you think it'll return a remainder when it produces a floating-point output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DIVSD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/divsd) handles scalar floating points and as such does not return a remainder. Instead it calculates as many decimals as possible for that type of floats.

From the Intel documentation:

```
# DIVSD (128-bit Legacy SSE version)
DEST[63:0] ← DEST[63:0] / SRC[63:0]
DEST[MAX_VL-1:64] (Unmodified)
```

Note that this is the same as the `FDIV` instruction.

You can of course use the usual-for-integer way of calculating the remainder by converting your result to integers, multiplying back, and then subtracting from the original number.

This can easily introduce huge rounding errors with floating point as this automatically produces catastrophic cancellation of most of the significant digits, if the divisor is much smaller than the dividend.  Avoiding this is why `fprem` is slower than `fdiv` + `frndint` + `fmul` + `fsub`.

Something like this (UNTESTED! Intel syntax)

```
; inputs: xmm1 divisor, xmm2 dividend
MOVAPS  xmm3, xmm2         ; xmm3 ← xmm2
DIVPS   xmm2, xmm1         ; xmm2 ← xmm2 ÷ xmm1
CVTPS2DQ xmm3, xmm2        ; xmm3 ← integers of xmm2
MULPS   xmm3, xmm1         ; xmm3 ← xmm3 × xmm1
MOVAPS  xmm4, xmm2         ; xmm4 ← xmm2
SUBPS   xmm4, xmm3         ; xmm4 ← xmm4 - xmm3
; xmm2 = xmm2 ÷ xmm1
; xmm4 = remainder (mathematically: frac(xmm2) × xmm1)
```

(Editor's note: does 4 packed single-precision floats in parallel.  Use `PD` (packed double) or `SD` (scalar double) if you want that.  Also note that SSE4.1 `roundps/pd` provides a safe way to round to the nearest integer for float values that might not fit in a 32-bit integer.)

---

A problem you may run into in using `FPREM` is the fact that you can't mix code using the Floating Point Unit and the MMX registers. They both end up using the same registers, but differently.

There is some documentation about that problem. If you don't use MMX registers, you'll be fine, though.

> *Source: Vol. 1 11-31 — PROGRAMMING WITH STREAMING SIMD EXTENSIONS 2 (SSE2)*
>
> 11.6.7 Interaction of SSE/SSE2 Instructions with x87 FPU and MMX Instructions
>
> The XMM registers and the x87 FPU and MMX registers represent separate execution environments, which has certain ramifications when executing SSE, SSE2, MMX, and x87 FPU instructions in the same code module or when mixing code modules that contain these instructions:
>
> • Those SSE and SSE2 instructions that operate only on XMM registers (such as the packed and scalar floating-point instructions and the 128-bit SIMD integer instructions) in the same instruction stream with64-bitSIMD integer or x87 FPU instructions without any restrictions. For example, an application can perform the
>
> majority of its floating-point computations in the XMM registers, using the packed and scalar floating-point instructions, and at the same time use the x87 FPU to perform trigonometric and other transcendental computations. Likewise, an application can perform packed 64-bit and 128-bit SIMD integer operations together without restrictions.
>
> • Those SSE and SSE2 instructions that operate on MMX registers (such as the CVTPS2PI, CVTTPS2PI, CVTPI2PS, CVTPD2PI, CVTTPD2PI, CVTPI2PD, MOVDQ2Q, MOVQ2DQ, PADDQ, and PSUBQ instructions) can also be executed in the same instruction stream as 64-bit SIMD integer or x87 FPU instructions, however, here they are subject to the restrictions on the simultaneous use of MMX technology and x87 FPU instructions, which include:
>
> — Transition from x87 FPU to MMX technology instructions or to SSE or SSE2 instructions that operate on MMX registers should be preceded by saving the state of the x87 FPU.
>
> — Transition from MMX technology instructions or from SSE or SSE2 instructions that operate on MMX registers to x87 FPU instructions should be preceded by execution of the EMMS instruction.

Since you have quite many XMM/YMM/ZMM registers, it is often worth the trouble of doing such things in SSE/AVX. The FPU, on the other hand, uses a stack which is much harder to handle in assembly.

Comment: You are misguided: the x87 FPU shares registers with MMX (which nobody uses) but not with SSE or AVX. Mixing x87 and SSE or AVX code is fine.

Comment: @Alexis, thanks much.  These are mixed doubles and integers, so it helps to have an XMM alternative for calculating a remainder.  I don't want to use the fpu if I can avoid it.

Comment: @fuz, thanks. I tighten that section of my answer as it can still be a problem if you somehow end up using MMX registers. I put the section that mentions that problem from the Intel documentation.

Comment: IMO the whole section about x87 vs. MMX is just noise.  MMX is mostly obsolete these days, and nothing in the question suggests any intent to use MMX.  It's not a likely gotcha so it's just a big distraction.